# How to convert 64 bit .deb file into 32 bit .deb file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, package, debian, deb

deb file of an application. I want to convert the same file into 32 bit .deb file.
So how to convert 64 bit .deb file into 32 bit .deb

Comment: Sunil, can you accept the top answer please? You should click the tick next to an answer to mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's not generally possible.

If .deb file contains any architecture specific files (ie libraries or executable binaries), then you'll need to obtain 32 bit versions of those files, or rebuild the package yourself from source.

If the contents of the .deb are already cross platform, then it should have already been marked as `Architecture: all` by the creator.

If the creator mistakenly marked a cross-platform package as platform specific, then you could manually edit the `Architecture` entry [in the control file](http://www.debian.org/doc/FAQ/ch-pkg_basics.en.html) yourself, but this seems like a rather unlikely situation.

Answer (score 2):

You need to rebuild the application from its sources for a 32 Bit target and use the packaging scripts it provides to build a DEB for x86.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you do not convert a package, you recompile its source for different platform and package it appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

impossible!
get source and recompile it for your self!

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible, but maybe need try virtualizing another OS or try *pbuilder*